# Change IP Cloudify Manager

Tags: cloudify

I did the Cloudify Manager installation on the Amazon cloud (http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.2/getting-started-bootstrapping.html), successfully.

However, to turn off the machine and start again, the IP is changed and when running:

```
cfy status
```

I get:

```
Getting management services status... [ip=54.83.41.97]
('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out'))
```

How do I change the IP 54.83.41.97 within the Coudify?

Answer (score 2):

The internal IP is set during bootstrap of the manager.
If your  internal IP has changed you should tear it down and bootstrap again.
If it is only the Elastic IP that changed you run:

```
cfy use -t your_new_ip
```

And the the CLI will connect to the manager with the new IP

Comment: I managed to successfully change IP. Just edit the file "~/cloudify-manager/.cloudify/context", changing the property "_management_ip".